# Loading N views of UICollectionView and reload at the end

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

[EDIT after replies: solution at the end of the question]

I have a UICollectionView where I initially load 4 views. I would like that when the user scrolls until the last one (4th view) and try to scroll again, I update the data of my model, reload the UICollectionView and moves back to the 1st view so that the user can again scroll 3 times till the 4th view, etc.

The issue is that when I load 4 views initially, the user can't scroll after he reached the last view since there is nothing after. So I created an empty cell as my 5th view and now I load 5 views in my initial UICollectionView. But this 5th view is never fully displayed and I use "willDisplay" method to reload the data and force the move back to the first view. This is not elegant but I couldn't find another way to do it.

This method is working fine but here is the problem: it seems that when willDisplay is called, I indeed reload the data and moves back to the first view but only then the scroll that was supposed to take me to the 5th view is taken into account which means that after I moved back to the first view, the app shows me actually the second view (it did move back to the first view but then the scroll that I initiated to go from 4th to 5th view is applied, moving me to the 2nd view).

I hope this is clear...

So here is the code I am using:

```swift
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) { 
// if this is the last view       
if((indexPath.row == self.dataModel.getNumberOfData()) && self.dataModel.getNumberOfData() > 0) 
{

// I update the model here
self.dataModel.resetData()
// Then I reload the UICollectionView
self.collectionView.reloadData()
// Then I move back to the first view
self.collectionView.selectItem(at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0), animated: false, scrollPosition: .centeredHorizontally)
}
}
```

Of course if you have another solution, more elegant, to avoid that 5th view, I am happy to consider it. My data is not static so when I need to reload the new data, I query a database to retrieve the new information so I don't know about the new data when I run the app.

Thanks.

[EDIT with a solution using scrollViewDidScroll. I show for example how to detect the end (horizontally scrolling and delete the first view...

```swift
override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
// if reached the end of the UICollectionView...
if (scrollView.contentOffset.x == scrollView.contentSize.width - scrollView.frame.size.width) {
print("Reached the end...")
self.dataModel.removeNFirst(n: 1) // remove first item from model
// delete the first view of the UICollectionView
self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
                self.collectionView.deleteItems(at: [IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)])
            }) { (finished) in
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
 }
}
```

Comment: “So I created an empty cell as my 5th view and now I load 5 views in my initial UICollectionView.” Seems crude. The usual thing is to act as the scroll view delegate so you can watch the user scroll, and load more data in response to the user scrolling to near the bottom.

Comment: There is a `tableView.visibleCells.last` property, maybe you can make use of it.

Comment: Just use `scrollViewDidScroll` to detect the end of the collectionView

Comment: Thanks all good using scrollViewDidScroll, it's much better for my case than using willDisplay(). I edited my question with the solution.